# How to format my JSON input to SQL insert statements

Tags: jq

How can I (generically) transform the input file below to output file below, using jq:

**Input file:**

```
[{"a": 1, "b": 10},
 {"a": 2, "d": "fred", "e": 30}]
```

**Output file:**

```
INSERT INTO mytab (a,b) VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO mytab (a,d,e) VALUES (2,"fred",30);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of string interpolation and two variants of string join operations, one using the `@csv` filter and other using `join(",")`

```
jq --raw-output '
  .[]| to_entries | map(.key) as $k | map(.value) as $v | 
    "INSERT INTO mytab (\($k | join(","))) VALUES (\($v | @csv ));"'
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ro_9xJzz0Y)

Comment: Re "*`map(to_entries)[]`*", `.[] | to_entries`. Seems really weird to build an array only to flatten it immediately afterwards.

Comment: If its just a matter of style, I'd like to keep it this way.

Comment: Also, `@csv`? Will that do the right thing for strings that contain `"` or `\ `?

Comment: @ikegami I'll leave it to the OP to decide, they want the values field to retain the original format, so can't use `join` for it

Comment: I don't understand. Whether `@csv` produces SQL literals or not is not something that needs to be decided.

Comment: @ikegami Please clarify with OP if you have questions on the presence of those characters. I presented my answer from OP's current input

Comment: Ah, so you're saying they're not compatible? If so, your assumption should be documented.

Comment: @Inian thanks, your solution works.  As a jq newbie, I will work thru to understand, and I may seek some clarifications.